# UICollectionViewCell is wider than specified in sizeForItemAt

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've created a `UICollectionView` using `UICollectionViewFlowLayout`. I specify the size of my `UICollectionViewCell` inside the `collectionView(_ collectionView:layout:sizeForItemAt:)` function:

```
extension FlickrPhotosViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let itemsPerRow: CGFloat = 3
    
    func collectionView(
        _ collectionView: UICollectionView,
        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
    ) -> CGSize {
        let paddingSpace = sectionInsets.left * (itemsPerRow + 1)
        let availableWidth = view.frame.width - paddingSpace
        let widthPerItem = availableWidth / itemsPerRow
        
        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }
}
```

I am expecting to see three images in one row (left image), however the images all have different size (right image)

[image: Correct layout]
[image: Wrong layout]

Answer (score 1):

`UICollectionViewFlowLayout` has a property `estimatedItemSize` which is likely set to `UICollectionViewFlowLayout.automaticSize`. This leads to the layout overriding the specified size in the `sizeForItemAt` function.

To fix this either set the property of the `UICollectionView` layout to `layout.estimatedItemSize = .zero` (for example in `viewDidLoad`) or use Interface Builder, select the *Collection View Flow Layout* object and in the Size Inspector set *Estimate Size* from *Automatic* to *None*

[image: Set estimated size of collection view flow layout]